# Function to replace missing with median for whole dataframe

Tags: r, replace, missing-data, median

I'm trying to write a function to replace missing values in columns with median, and that this works for both factors/characters and numerical values.

```
library(dplyr)
test = data.frame(a=1:6,b=c("a","b",NA,NA,NA,"c"),c=c(1,1,1,1,2,NA),d=c("a","a","c",NA,NA,"b"))

fun_rep_na = function(df){
  for(i in colnames(df)){
    j<-sym(i)
    df = df %>% mutate(!!j=if_else(is.na(!!j),median(!!j, na.rm=TRUE),!!j))
  }
}
```

I see that *tidyr* has a function called replace_na, but I'm not sure how to use this either. Anyway, a custom function is what I would like.

The code above gives me an error.

Comment: You don't need a for loop use `mutate_all`.  BTW, `median` need a numeric column

Comment: How do you calculate median values of `factor` and `character` columns ?

Comment: @akrun: Ah, great, thanks, I didn't know that <3 But how do I then specifiy what to replace with? I know about the median of factor, but I would like it to replace most used values in that case. Sorry I'm useless.

Comment: @RonakShah: I know, but median is per definition the value most repeated, right? :)

Comment: It's not very wise to impute missings with the median (Allison, 2002), I strongly reccomend to consult a statistician.

Comment: @jay.sf: what would be the alternative?

Comment: @Helen read e.g. Allison, Paul D. 2002. Missing Data. SAGE Publications, Inc.

Comment: I dont thave time to buy a book right now :/

Comment: @Helen so spend some money and hire a statistician :)

Comment: @jay.sf: I am a statistician.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate_if` with `median` as `median` works only on `numeric` columns

```
test %>% 
   mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~ replace(., is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```

---

If we want the value most repeated, then we may need `Mode`

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

The `Mode` function was first updated here

```
test %>% 
  mutate_all(list(~ replace(., is.na(.), Mode(.))))
#  a b c d
#1 1 a 1 a
#2 2 b 1 a
#3 3 a 1 c
#4 4 a 1 a
#5 5 a 2 a
#6 6 c 1 b
```

Comment: Ah that looks beautiful. Could you explain what the ~ does and all the dots?

Comment: @Helen It is a tilda operator used to make the anonymous function call concise  in tidyverse, otherwise, you may need `function(x) replace(x, is.na(x),`

Comment: What is the anonymous function and what is concise? Could you point me in the right direction where to read about this?

Comment: @Helen An anonymous function is one used in many languages (sometimes, known as `lambda` function).  For e.g. with python it would be `lambda x: x * 5` or using R, `lapply(1:5, function(x) x: (x + 5))`   If you have checked `map` and other functions, the conciseness is `map(1:5, ~ .x:(.x + 5))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `Mode` and not median

Taking `Mode` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/3962914)

```
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

library(dplyr)

test %>%  mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), Mode(na.omit(.))))

#  a b c d
#1 1 a 1 a
#2 2 b 1 a
#3 3 a 1 c
#4 4 a 1 a
#5 5 a 2 a
#6 6 c 1 b
```